Знаки препинания в БСП при противопоставлении
Какой знак препинания вы поставите на месте скобок в этом предложении?
Это вопрос из теста. С ответом не согласен.

География как наука зародилась в античные времена(—,) геология как
самостоятельная ветвь начала развиваться только во второй половине 18
века.


• Похоже, что имеется в виду вот эта рекомендация из правил Розенталя (Знаки препинания в бессоюзном сложном предложении):

§ 45. 2. Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если в ней выражено противопоставление по отношению к содержанию первой части (между частями можно вставить союз но или а): <...> Не раны, не больное лёгкое мучило его — раздражало сознание ненужности (Павл.); Я за свечку — свечка в печку (Чук.)...

Пунктуация в БСП — это такая каверзная тема...
Взять хотя бы пример про свечку. У Чуковского есть совершенно другой вариант написания:
Я за свечку,
Свечка — в печку!
"Мойдодыр"
• Если слепо следовать правилам и подставить союз, то между частями БСП необходимо тире (смысл: противопоставление времён возникновения наук; кстати, не мешало бы наращение добавить к числительному):
География как наука зародилась в античные времена — [а] геология как самостоятельная ветвь начала развиваться только во второй половине 18-го века.
• Если же в предложении просто констатируется время, когда науки возникли, то части БСП становятся близкими по смыслу и ставится не тире, а запятая (§ 43).
✦ В тесте, скорее всего, правильный вариант, подогнанный под правила, — тире.
Я же считаю, что без контекста выбрать нужный знак нет возможности.

Рима Михайлова, соглашусь с вами. Но в приведенных вами примерах, явно напрашивается тире по интонации и по структуре. В этом предложении даже рука не тянется поставить тире.

В тесте, увы, нет контекста.

Ну, Серж, это ведь не мои примеры, а Розенталя (я ведь привела ссылку). И среди них, конечно же, имеются и некороткие. В сказках Андерсена обретают дар речи не только цветы, ветры, деревья — в них оживает и домашний мир вещей и игрушек (Пауст.)

Я говорю о своем тексте.

Когда в БСП можно поставить запятую и можно ли это сделать в заданном предложении (по учебнику для вузов Г. И.  Кустовой)
БСП ОДНОРОДНОГО СОСТАВА

Перечислительные отношения

Предложения выражают одновременность или последовательность событий. Интонация нисходяще-нисходящая с полным понижением голоса в конце первой части: Шумел ветер, лил дождь,
на улице было темно — одновременность событий в прошлом; Зазвонил телефон, отец взял трубку — последовательность событий в прошлом.
Примечание. Если в перечислительных БСП появляется добавочное причинно-следственное значение, они превращаются в предложения неоднородного состава, сравним: Зазвонил телефон — отец нахмурился.
2. Сопоставление и противопоставление
Это предложения однородного состава, но закрытой структуры (двучленные). Интонация восходяще-нисходящая: Ты богат — я очень беден, / / Ты прозаик — я поэт (П.)
Структурные элементы: 1) лексика, выражающая сопоставление и противопоставление; 2) видо-временные формы глаголов-сказуемых; 3) обычен синтаксический параллелизм предикативных частей; 4) возможен общий член.
Синонимы: ССП с сопоставительным значением; СПП с придаточным сопоставительным.
БСП НЕОДНОРОДНОГО СОСТАВА

Распространительно-присоединительное отношения

Нисходяще-нисходящая интонация с полным понижением голоса в конце первой части. Вторая часть может распространять
всю первую часть или одно слово в первой части:
Был, словом, у Понтия Пилата, за это я ручаюсь (Б.); Мы заблудились, этого я и боялся (сравним синонимичное СПП с придаточным присоединительным: Мы заблудились, чего я и боялся); Мы подошли к реке, за ней простирались поля (сравним синонимичное СПП с придаточным атрибутивно-распространительным: Подошли к реке, за которой простирались поля).
Структурные элементы: 1) анафорические местоимения и указательные местоимения и частицы в анафорической функции во второй части; 2) фиксированный порядок частей.
Синонимы: СПП с  с распространительным значением,
СПП с придаточным присоединительным, ССП с соединительно-распространительным значением.
ВЫВОД (по предложению)
География как наука зародилась в античные времена(—,) геология как самостоятельная ветвь начала развиваться только во второй половине 18 века.

Можно ли здесь поставить запятую?

(1) Это однородные (независимые) отношения?  Нет! Здесь явное сопоставление двух сообщений о времени появления наук, то есть нет однородности.
(2) Это неоднородные распространительные отношения, то есть вторая тема продолжает первую? Что-то не похоже, связь скорее параллельная. Связующих местоимений нет, у двух сообщений одна тема времени, но сопоставляются две разные науки.

Тогда смотрим тему тире и значение сопоставления. Давайте ИЗМЕНИМ предложение:

География как наука зародилась в античные времена — геология  начала развиваться только во второй половине 18 века.
Вот теперь можно поставить тире, то есть структура подходит под восходяще-нисходящую интонацию (я ее называю разделительной). Чувствуете разницу? Значит,  мешал оборот речи как самостоятельная ветвь, из-за него не было параллельной структуры.
Соответственно, хотелось по интонации поставить запятую, но она по семантике не подходит никаким образом. Вот и делайте свои выводы.

Вы убрали целый оборот речи и предлагаете поставить тире. Но ведь из теста его убрать нельзя.

Как говорится, нельзя, но нужно.  Я убрала тире для того, чтобы вы поняли, в каком предложении нужно поставить тире, и только тире. Так выглядят сопоставит. однород. отношения и разделительная интонация, когда ставится тире.  У вас не так, значит, надо брать не БСП, а союзную связь (СПП или ССП). И стилистику подобрать нужную. А вот почему лингвисты из Омска за запятую, я не знаю.  И какая у них запятая? Перечислительная не подойдет, да и для присоединительной показаний тоже нет. Кстати, и нашим отвечающим замечание. Выбирая запятую в БСП, не забывайте указывать ее вид)  такая милая шутка)

Ну так это задание из теста. А значит, они откуда-то взяли это предложение. Откуда — не знаю. И если попытаться оспорить, предложив правку предложения, ничего не выйдет.

Ну и что вы в конечно итоге выберете, чем надо пожертвовать?  Интонацией (тогда ставим тире) или смыслом (тогда ставим запятую)? Наверное, лучше интонацией) // Кстати, предложение можно самим придумать, надо у них еще географию с геологией проверить) В конце концов, убрать союз ничего не стоит.

Sharon, я полностью согласен с вашими доводами. Но, увы!

Ну ладно, пусть живут)

В качестве варианта:
География как наука / зародилась в античные времена, — геология как самостоятельная ветвь / начала развиваться / только во второй половине XVIII века.
Пояснение

Это БСП, сопоставительные отношения. Тире для обозначения таких отношений не подойдет, как и запятая.

Интонация — это основное средство связи в БСП. Для выражения сопоставительных отношений нужен сильный знак, поэтому запятой недостаточно.
А тире не подходит по структуре, так как  обе части надо дополнительно делить на фрагменты (синтагмы) при произношении. В то же время  интонация для тире должна быть разделительной, как в "Я за свечку — свечка в печку", где мы сопоставляем короткие фразы.
По интонации подойдет только единый знак с увеличенной паузой, но он нехарактерен для подобных предложений, а для теста вообще не подойдет.  Поэтому лучше использовать СПП, но  это не по теме.  Соответственно,  предложение выбрано или построено не совсем удачно.

СПП как синтаксический аналог:

География как наука зародилась в античные времена, В ТО ВРЕМЯ КАК геология в качестве самостоятельной ветви начала развиваться только во второй половине XVIII века.
ССП с сочинительным противительным союзом А не подойдет по семантике, так как сопоставление двух наук здесь делается по времени их возникновения. (С помощью союза А можно сопоставить науки по нескольким различным ситуациям.)

Sharon, Вы и вправду считаете свой предложенный вариант правильным? География как наука зародилась в античные времена, в то время как геология как самостоятельная ветвь начала развиваться только во второй половине XVIII века. Чем же стилистически он лучше оригинального предложения?

Шарон, соглашусь. Но надо выбирать из того, что есть.

Выбирайте!  Вы-то что выбрали, мне интересно?  Ответ, где вам предлагали поставить ЗАПЯТУЮ? Вот этот:  • Если же в предложении просто констатируется время, когда науки возникли, то части БСП становятся БЛИЗКИМИ по смыслу и ставится не тире, а запятая. О чем это?  Я не понимаю. Вы там видите БЛИЗОСТЬ ПО СМЫСЛУ? Поясните, пожалуйста.  (А контекст, которого к сожалению нет, можно предположить.)  С другой стороны, конформизм - удобная позиция, не правда ли?  Недавно такое обсуждали. Нужно писать НН, но и Н не будет ошибкой.

Почему в ответе неправильно определены отношения? Это сопоставление, а не противопоставление, можно такие отношения обозначать  запятой?  Вы же филолог,  знаете, как в высшей школе делается анализ. Но вы и с этим соглашаетесь. Мне вот интересно: как выглядит короткий ответ без конформизма с вашей точки зрения, то есть ответ и короткое обоснование. Напишите, пожалуйста, ваш ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ответ.  Или, может, у Грамоты спросить?

@Sharon я за запятую. На мой взгляд, здесь просто констатируется время появление наук, а их сопоставление. К тому же, как вы верно заметили, в справочниках обычно приводятся короткие фразы.

Sharon, да, здесь сопоставление. Но какие отношения имели в виду составители теста, мне точно неизвестно. По-моему, противопоставление. Тесты я пока сам не видел.

Я задал Грамоте. И не только. И лингвистам Омского института на сайте Современный русский язык. Те тоже ответили, что здесь более уместна запятая.

Отлично! Это класс! Но в ответе названы два варианта, приоритет за тире. Так дайте свой ответ, а также ответы специалистов, вот и примете этот вариант. А так какая польза от вашей темы для тех, кто посещает сайт? Два варианта с сомнительным обоснованием запятой? // Я тогда с вашего позволения напишу конспектик по Кустовой о запятой в БСП.

@Sharon, два варианта указал я. Потому что я за запятую. В тестах стоит тире. Иначе я зал бы этот вопрос.

Пишите, буду ждать вашего ответа.

Мне удалось найти текст. В оригинале это предложение выглядит по-другому, это уже сами авторы объединили два предложения в одно и поставили тире.
